# how to display a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have a div `#items` which wraps around a whole bunch of `.item`. I want to display the items side by side, and if they exceed the width of the page, display a horizontal scroll bar.

```
<div id="somediv"></div>

<div id="items">
   <div class="item">
     Item content
   </div>
</div>

<div id="someotherdiv"></div>
```

I tried something like this but it does not work

```
#items{
   overflow: auto;
   width:100%;
   height:200px;       /* this is the height of each item*/ 
}
.item{
   float:left;      
}
```

I thought this was the way to do it, but I can't get this to way to work, so I'm open to corrections and other ways also.

Comment: If your container is specifying a width this won't exceed that. Could you post your html and css (body and wrapper divs)

Comment: @Grillz My body doesn't have any width, but my wrapper has `width:800px;`

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right path, but you will need and extra wrapper to make it work...

```
<div id="scrollable">
<div id="items">
   <div class="item">
     Item content
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and then your CSS:

```
    #scrollable {
       overflow: auto;
       width:100%;
       height:200px; 
    }

   #items {
     width: 3000px; /* itemWidth x itemCount */
    }

  .item{
     float:left;      
  }
```

Comment: Never made a horizontal scrollbar, because I personally hate them.  But this works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This previous question may help:
[CSS div element - how to show horizontal scroll bars only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only)

So instead of your current css, change it to:

```
#items{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:200px
}
.item{
    float:left;
}
```

Try that and adjust if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to [/how-to-force-horizontal-scrolling-in-an-html-list-using-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707807/how-to-force-horizontal-scrolling-in-an-html-list-using-css) where [animuson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) explained that floated elements cannot be measured.

```
#items{
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
width:100%;
height:200px
}

.item{
display: inline-block;
}
```

And the same [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you not to provide width for #items. In my case, the number of .item was dynamic and summing them up was not in my preference.

```
#items{
            overflow: auto;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }

.item {             
            display:inline;
        }
```