# how to force horizontal scrolling in an HTML list using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-float, horizontal-scrolling

I have a list like this:

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
     <li>four</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
ul { 
     width: 160px;
     height: 100px;
     overflow: auto; 
     }
li { 
     width: 80px;
     display: inline-block;
     float: left 
     }
```

I'm trying to force the list items to display from left to right, that is

```
 one - two - three - four
```

**My problem:**
Doing it like this gives me two rows with two items each.

**Question:**
Is there a CSS way to force the list items to all be in a single row so I can use horizontal scrolling? Right now if I set *overflow:auto* I'm only getting vertical scrollbars, which I don't want.

I don't want to set this on the wrapping div. I'm just curious if there is a CSS solution I can use within the list alone.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't really scroll floated content. Once it's floated, it's not calculated in the width or height of the parent container by default. Really the `<ul>` is just expanding to its set width and then not doing anything else.

Removing the `float: left` will make them scrollable. The only problem you'll have then is that there is the extra "space" between each inline-block. You can remove that by removing the line-breaks between each list item. It's not the prettiest thing. Normally I'd use a `font-size: 0` and then reset the font-size in the list item.

You also need to make sure the items don't wrap to a new line when they hit the width of the element.

**jsFiddle Examples:**

- [Removing line breaks](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/)
- [Using `font-size: 0`](http://jsfiddle.net/UTUsS/)

Comment: First jsFiddle link of the above two is dead.

Answer (score 39):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnYb5/

**Relevant CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:auto;
}

li{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: The `height` there is not actually doing anything related to the scrollbar. In fact, it's just making the content cut off. http://jsfiddle.net/nPmLe/1/ - This answer is just misinformation hidden behind other properties which are actually doing the work. The height does not need constrained whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't constrained the height of the `<ul>`, so the browser is free to wrap the 'extra' elements onto their own line. You'll need a `height: 1em` or whatever to make sure the `<ul>` can't get taller, forcing everything to scroll horizontally.

Comment: nope. Doesn't work. The list items don't seem to care and if I'm setting overflow: auto, I only get vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow-x: scroll;` on the div.

Fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfw2a/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with css+javascript, e.g. (http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/v1-2.htm). Don't think there is a CSS-only sulution (that will work cross-browser).