# Div overflow beyond browser width without setting width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div where instead of the images inside moving to the next line it just keeps overflowing beyond the browser width.

**HTML Markup:**

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.carousel {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.carousel img{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there anyway to do this without setting a width to the div?

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aDpFB)

Comment: The idea is pretty similar to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707807/how-to-force-horizontal-scrolling-in-an-html-list-using-css :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to your `.carousel` div:

```
.carousel {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iCqtc

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the other answer, if you want the carousel to scroll horizontally instead of hiding its overflow, you can hide `overflow-y` and set `overflow-x` to scroll:

```
.carousel
{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Check the example.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLJGf)