# Overflow-x not working

Tags: css, scroll

I am trying to implement a slider for my gallery.
Right now,the css has an issue where the overflow-x doesnt work properly.
(I want a horizontal slider and no vertical scroll)

Here's the [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/nevinm/6H43f/)

Please do take a look.

```
.testimg{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#testDiv{
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    border:1px solid black; 
}
.testimgdiv{
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707807/how-to-force-horizontal-scrolling-in-an-html-list-using-css

Comment: @davidpauljunior Didnt work... tried that already

Comment: And for who ever down voted this,please do explain why..

Comment: Gave an upvote to even it out.  Thought the downvote was harsh.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Once you've floated the elements, you've taken them out the document flow and it won't be calculated in the parent's width.  You have to use a combination of `display: inline-block` on the items instead of float, and then use `white-space: nowrap` on the parent.

```
#testDiv{
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  font-size: 0;
}
.testimgdiv{
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/6H43f/2/)**

Note: I'm using `font-size: 0` to make the items appear right next to each other.

**UPDATE**

As this post is quite old, it's probably worth noting that this can be done with less code using flexbox (depending on the browser support level required):

```css
#testDiv {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.testimgdiv {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">
  <div class='testimgdiv'>
    <img class="testimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/" />
  </div>
  <div class='testimgdiv'>
    <img class="testimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/" />
  </div>
  <div class='testimgdiv'>
    <img class="testimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/" />
  </div>
  <div class='testimgdiv'>
    <img class="testimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/" />
  </div>
  <div class='testimgdiv'>
    <img class="testimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/" />
  </div>
  <div class='testimgdiv'>
    <img class="testimg" src="https://picsum.photos/100/100/" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does font-size:0 make it appear one after the other?

Comment: How to use overflow-x with float elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
#testDiv {
   border: 1px solid #FF0000;
   float: left;
   height: auto;
   overflow-x: auto;
   width: 400px;
}
```