# How can I make it to scroll Horizontally?

Tags: html, css

How can I make it to scroll  Horizontally?
HTML

text

```
             <a href="html"><div id="right" class="box">
                <p>text</P>
            </div></a>
```

CSS

```
#big{
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    border: thin solid black;
    overflow-x: show;
    overflow-y: hidden;
```

}
    }

```
.box {
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you want ?

Comment: Scroll what ?   I mean, what you want to scroll ?

Comment: where is #big in your html?

Comment: Also `overflow-x: show;` is not a  valid rule. I think you are looking for `overflow-x: auto`;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are declaring different ID name in the css and html DOM element, pay attention with that.

Second, there's no such value show to overflow property, check here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

HTML

```
<a href="html">
  <div id="right" class="box">
    <p>text</p> <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p> <p>text</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#right{
    background-color: red;
    width: 3200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    border: thin solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.box {
text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/13jh7gjb/2/

I hope it helps, just remove the color of the background, I`ve added to highlight the div for you..

Comment: this is vertical scroll, OP wants horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Add these following CSS codes to your container.

overflow-x: scroll;

overflow-y: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, maybe you will find your answer in this post :

Here the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707807/how-to-force-horizontal-scrolling-in-an-html-list-using-css) post, here the suggestion
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/)

```css
ul { 
     width: 160px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: auto; 
     }
li { 
     width: 80px;
     display: inline-block;
     }
```

```html
<div>
   <ul>
     <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```