# How to lock scrolling of a web page temporarily?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I lock scrolling of a webpage temporarily when a dialog box is displayed ?  I have a dialog box within which I want to enable scrolling **after deactivating scrolling from the overlayed webpage**.

**Is there a js command to *temporarily* disable scrolling ?**

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/programmatically-disable-scrolling

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could set a container element or maybe even the body to `overflow: hidden` with a width and height of the browser window. This way any overflowing content will fall off the page and scroll bars are never displayed. This can be set in a css statement like `body.dialog-open { overflow: hidden; }`. You can then add and remove the `.dialog-open` classname when the dialog opens and closes.

The width and height might not be required if setting this on the body, but I'd have to check browser compatibility on that one. Might get some unexpected results there.

edit:
If you want scrolling inside your dialog you can set `overflow: auto` there, with a height set on that element.

Older browsers (most notably IE) might show a horizontal scrollbar as well, you might have to set `overflow-x: hidden` if that is the case.

Also see: [CSS div element - how to show horizontal scroll bars only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only) for more information on scrollbars.

Comment: Also beware that Opera has an old bug causing it to ignore overflow:hidden when using the scroll wheel. (No easy workaround either)

Comment: Initially the webpage is scrollable, but only for the time dialog isdisabled, I want to temporarily disable scrolling, so I guess your sol. wont work

Comment: It will. You can just add a classname to the body when the dialog opens, and remove it when it closes. Will update the post to add this.

Comment: he asked for JavaScript

Comment: This removes the scrollbar from the viewport and messes with the `<html>` element.

Comment: BUG WARNING: Every solution I have found online like this causes a problem if you use Google ReCapcha within a FORM element in the popup. When the Google ReCapcha triggers its own popup within a form element in your popup it may be 1000s of pixels "above" where it should be, and the user can not scroll to it. Just watched this destroy the conversion rate on several landing pages that had "popup forms" with "locked" scroll bars... because people could not complete the ReCapcha

Answer (score 28):

**EDIT** Try this:

On dialog open (remove scrollbar and prevent user from scrolling):

```
  $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
  $(document).bind('scroll',function () { 
       window.scrollTo(0,0); 
  });
```

On Dialog Close(allow user to scroll again):

```
 $(document).unbind('scroll'); 
  $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
```

Comment: THIS. Thank you so much. I was looking for hours to find something like this. It's the only really working solution on all browsers I tested so far.

Comment: @Limpan just out of curiosity why do you need the eventListener as well? in major browsers setting overflow to hidden is enough

Comment: BUG WARNING: Every solution I have found online like this causes a problem if you use Google ReCapcha within a FORM element in the popup. When the Google ReCapcha triggers its own popup within a form element in your popup it may be 1000s of pixels "above" where it should be, and the user can not scroll to it. Just watched this destroy the conversion rate on several landing pages that had "popup forms" with "locked" scroll bars... because people could not complete the ReCapcha

Comment: @halafi, I'm not sure but it seems like it prevents programmatic scrolling with `window.scrollTo()`, by scrolling to top.

Answer (score 5):

Here is vanilla JS version:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
...
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'visible' // the default for the css property
```

Answer (score 1):

*It's a copy of my answer that I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63221105/4336168*

I use these two functions for this:

```js
function enableBodyScroll() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    document.body.style.position = '';
    document.body.style.overflowY = '';

    if (document.body.style.marginTop) {
      const scrollTop = -parseInt(document.body.style.marginTop, 10);
      document.body.style.marginTop = '';
      window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, scrollTop);
    }
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', enableBodyScroll);
  }
}

function disableBodyScroll({ savePosition = false } = {}) {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    if (document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight) {
      if (savePosition) document.body.style.marginTop = `-${window.pageYOffset}px`;
      document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
      document.body.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
    }
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => disableBodyScroll({ savePosition }));
  }
}
```

How it works:

1. When you want to disable the scroll with saving the current position, you run `disableBodyScroll({ savePosition: true })`.
2. The function check whether the page loaded or not (because user may trigger dialog opening during the loading).
3. If the page is loaded, it saves current scroll position by setting `margin-top` on `body`, then it sets `position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll` on it to remove scrollbar.
4. If the page isn't loaded, it adds event listener to run (3.) when the page loads.

For enabling scroll everything is the same, but the function remove styles instead of setting them.

[Source of the code](https://github.com/funbox/diamonds/blob/master/lib/body-scroll.ts), so they can be used like this:

```sh
npm install --save @funboxteam/diamonds
```

```js
import { enableBodyScroll, disableBodyScroll } from '@funboxteam/diamonds';
```

Comment: After running the "enableBodyScroll()" function it scroll the body from top, how can i prevent it. I want to enable scroll from the exact location where the scroll was locked.

Comment: @AnujThapa, if you passed `savePosition: true` to `disableBodyScroll`, then the scrolled position will be saved, and `enableBodyScroll` will respect this position.