# Disable browser window scrolling of any kind?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

Is there a way to disable scrolling? Not just the scrollbar, but the entire functionality from the browser window?

Comment: See this, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily

Answer (score 26):

based on your answer to Keit you dont want to scroll be active when you have a lightbox open?
if that is the case you can add a class to the body at the same time as you open the lightbox with the following css

And the nice thing about this solution it keeps the scroll "space" so the site do not jump, its more like it disables it. hope this helps

```
body.noscroll
{
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}



$('body').addClass('noscroll');
$('body').removeClass('noscroll');
```

Comment: I'm surprised this does not have an outrageous number of votes on it. Very efficient. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesn't work for me. This works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411282/how-to-lock-scrolling-of-a-web-page-temporarily/6411611#6411611

Answer (score 9):

CSS

```
body
{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

javascript

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

jQuery

```
$("body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: That hides the scrollbar and generally "disables" the scroll function. However, in GWT have a popup window with some anchors and a div. When the anchor is clicked, it not only scrolls within the div, but also scrolls the page in the background.

Answer (score 3):

If your GWT application is alone in your web page, you can use:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
// ...

Window.enableScrolling(false);
```

for example in your `onModuleLoad` function.