# Lock scrolling while input(type=checkbox) is checked

Tags: javascript, scroll

I've made a CSS-only modal using an input with type=checkbox. Now I want to.. well, I want to make a few things happen, and I may post a few more questions as I continue development, but firstly, I'm trying to lock scrolling ability while the modal is open. I've tried this:

```
var modalToggle = document.getElementById('vids');

function isOpen() {
 if(modalToggle.checked === true) {
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
 }
}

modalToggle.addEventListener('click', isOpen());
```

as was suggested in this question

[How to lock scrolling of a web page temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411282/how-to-lock-scrolling-of-a-web-page-temporarily)

But the style does not get applied to the body. In fact, the body doesn't even have anything in it (yet) aside from the landing screen (containing the modal) with `height: 100vh;` and a blank div with `height: 1000px;` I created solely for scroll-testing purposes. Considering that, I tried this:

```
var modalToggle = document.getElementById('vids');
var space = document.getElementById('space');

function isOpen() {
 if(modalToggle.checked === true) {
  space.style.display = "none";
 }
}

modalToggle.addEventListener('click', isOpen());
```

still, the style is not applied... To be sure, I'm new to javascript, but I simply can't see how this doesn't work...

Comment: Remove execute when you add event. Use `modalToggle.addEventListener('click', isOpen);` instead of `modalToggle.addEventListener('click', isOpen());`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!! Again, still new to javascript, and I still have yet to really understand what that 'execute' section of a function really does....

Comment: You might need to read [How to use Callback](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

Comment: Definitely will do!! Multiple times, most likely. Thanks again!!