# How do I make a div that can scroll left/right using the mousewheel?

Tags: html, css, scroll, mousewheel

But when the user scrolls up and down using the mouse wheel, it scrolls the div left and right.

Comment: Does the div have a vertical as well as horizontal?

Comment: You're seeing it do this?  Or you want it to do this?  I urge you to clarify your exact question and post some code.

Comment: @sparky the title is pretty clear: How do I make a div that can scroll left/right?

Comment: May help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only

Comment: @Trey:  Oh really?  Is he **REQUESTING** for it to scroll left/right with the mouse-wheel's up/down or is he **OBSERVING** a left/right movement with the mouse-wheel's up/down?  Who knows since he hasn't posted the code he's using.

Comment: @sparky yes really, the first three words "How do I" clearly seem to indicate that he wants to employ this functionality.

Comment: @Trey: Try again.  _"But when the user scrolls up and down using the mouse wheel, it scrolls the div left and right."_  **Is this what he wants or what his code is currently doing?**

Comment: @Sparky, it is what he wants, but it's an ambiguous question. @Owalla, I really, really hope that you have a very good reason to mess with the default browser behaviour.

Comment: i think he meant `up and down` instead of `left and right` in `..using the mouse wheel, it scrolls the div left and right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use JavaScript. This page details the different events and how to use them:

[Mouse wheel programming in JavaScript](http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/).

Answer (score 1):

I have used prototype to hook the events. This is the simplest I can do to get a div to scroll horizontally using mouse wheel. It doesn't really matter if you keep the overflow to auto/scroll/hidden. Please try it in different browsers. I am not sure about the event in other browsers. I mostly did this in IE as I code in IE.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js type="text/javascript"></script>
<div style="width:100px;height:150px;overflow:auto;" id="myDiv">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<script language="javascript">
    function handleScroll(e) {
        var delta = 0;
        var upScroll = true;

        if (!e) e = window.event;
        if (event.wheelDelta) {
            delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        } else if (event.detail) { delta = -event.detail / 3; }

        // increments or decrements the scroll left
        var div =  $('myDiv');
        div.scrollLeft = (div.scrollLeft + Math.round(delta) + ((delta > 0) ? 50 : -50));
    }

    // hook events
    Event.observe($('myDiv'), "mousewheel", handleScroll, false);
    Event.observe($('myDiv'), "DOMMouseScroll", handleScroll, false); // Firefox
</script>
```