# CSS - Show only Horizontal Scroll bar for a fixed width and height div

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I got a div which is of fixed width and height:

```
 #containersimg
 {
    width: 900px;
    height: 135px;
 }
```

And I have many images inside, with width 90px and height 120px. So i want to have my images all in a row, and show only horizontal scroll bar to scroll through the images.

I need to make this work in both FF and IE8 and above. I tried the overflow-x and overflow-y but I didn't helped.

Any idea?? Hope can get some help here... thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a wrapping div inside your scrolling container to ensure that they are not constrained by width and then set `overflow-x: scroll` on the container.  I've mocked up a quick fiddle to demonstrate. http://jsfiddle.net/vUEYG/

Comment: +1 Good, but I think it's better to give `.square` `display:inline-block` and remove `float:left`. Then give `.wrapper` `white-space:nowrap` and remove the `width` from it. This way you are not limited to 500px width for wrapper. Se here: http://jsfiddle.net/WbVp3/

Comment: That would make more sense actually.  I've updated the fiddle with your suggestions - also changed the square divs to spans to make sure IE handles them properly with inline-block.  http://jsfiddle.net/vUEYG/2/

Comment: hi, thanks a lot. But due to some reasons, i could not change the html construct... any idea hw to do that without adding div?? thanks..

Comment: You might be able to lose the wrapper div now actually and just set `white-space:nowrap` on that http://jsfiddle.net/vUEYG/3/

Comment: Brilliant that we managed to find the perfect solution together :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go :)

```
-ms-overflow-x: hidden;
```

Taken from this great resource [CSS div element - how to show horizontal scroll bars only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only)

Comment: Can you put your code into a JS fiddle please :) That will allow us to assist better :)

Comment: Hi, here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/yenni104/rTjmc/ 
Got a solution from above posted answer, still thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can add first overflow:auto

```
#containersimg
 {
    width: 900px;
    height: 135px;
overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;


 }
```

may help you