# Horizontal scrollable images row without list

Tags: html, css

I want to create a scrollable row with thumbnails in a (smaller) container div.

Is this possible without wrapping the img in a list? I tried with

```
float:left
display: inline-block;
```

for the images

and/or

```
overflow: auto;
```

in the container div.

But the divs appear in a column and no horizontal scrollbar appears (only vertical when using overflow:auto).

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qJSr/1/

Comment: Did you give the containing `div` a fixed size? Also, you probably want `overflow: scroll-x;`

Comment: And you missed a `;` at the end of your float statement. (Do you even need the `float` when you have inline-block for your purposes?)

Comment: the div has a fixed size, and I added overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden. Now I see a horizontal scrollbar but it's disabled and the images are still aligned vertically instead of horizontally. thomthom: ; was a typo. Removing float doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS div element - how to show horizontal scroll bars only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping the images within a wrapper that is scrolled inside of an outer wrapper you can achieve this quite easily.

jsfiddle link: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3KQYy/2/);

The HTML:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="innerwrapper">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
   </div>
 </div>​
```

The CSS:

```
#wrapper { height: 100px; overflow: auto; width: 500px; overflow-y: hidden;}
img {height: 100px; width: 200px;float: left;}
#innerwrapper { width: 1200px;}​
```

Comment: Works, but that's a lot of wrappers :/

Comment: I updated it, it's just one wrapper with all the img tags in it c:

Comment: Ok it works. it's possible to simplify a bit more removing display: inline-block; and position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

If you contain your images within an oblong shaped div then the css above should work.

Answer (score 0):

`float:left;` will work fine. For a markup as such

```
<div id="collection">
   <img ... />
   ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#collection {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#collection img { float:left }
```