# Enable scrolling in CGridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii

Is there any solution to enable scrolling in CGridView?I dont want to use yii extensions.I just wanna work with standard CGridView.

Answer (score 2):

To enable scrolling in the CGridView, you just put a div around it and then set the overflow using CSS. You will need to set the height.

[CSS div element - how to show horizontal scroll bars only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only)