# display tree structure with very large depth in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, recursion

On a JSP page, a tree with large number of nodes is loaded. Tree is displayed in the diagonal manner like shown below

```
Root
 |
 |----Dependencies
 |        |----A
 |        |----B
 |        |----Dependencies 
                    |----A
                    |----B
                    |----Dependencies ...........    
                              |
                              |
                              |
                              n
```

Since it is larger than the page size so vertical scroll bar comes.
But the issue is **no horizontal scroll bar is coming. Tree has so many nodes that it goes diagonally till end point of the page and afterwards it again starts with left most point but not in tree like structure. Rest of the tree nodes are simply displayed as a list as shown below**

```
Dependencies
A
B
C
|
|
n
```

Please suggest how can I display such a large tree on my JSP page. Is there any browser limitation? Or should I use some other approach to display such a large tree?

Comment: Can you try put that output into `<pre></pre>` tags?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/258372/1065197. By the way, your question is HTML/CSS related, not Java nor JavaScript nor recursion (yes, you present it in a JSP and use a Java function to load the data, but the presentation is in the end pure HTML/CSS code).

Comment: Must all those nodes be expanded?