# How to have a highcharts chart in a container of a fixed width, and with a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, scroll

The variation of the size (number of points on the x-axis) of my charts is broad. So, when there are too many points, the labels get mixed/overlapped.
I want to change the width of the chart dynamically.

I don't want the container width to change coz then i'll have to change the width of the page to fit (change the general layout) which I did and it didn't look good.

Instead I want to keep the same width of the container, but to have a horizontal scrollbar to it that will enable me to navigate the chart (whose width is dynamically determined).

I talked a lot but I hope it's clear.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?...Can you offer code example, screenshot, or a jsfiddle to help us help you?

Comment: I tried the suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258372/css-div-element-how-to-show-horizontal-scroll-bars-only/8319119#8319119 and couldn't make it work. But the suggestion given by MikeM works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) (or [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)) on the container element to provide horizontal scrolling for just that container.

<kbd>[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/WqC9z/)</kbd>

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    margin: 40px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
#chart {
    background: gray url(//placehold.it/3000x300&text=Some+Chart);
    height: 300px;
    width: 3000px;
}
```

note: `overflow-x`/`overflow-y` are not supported in IE8 and below, use `overflow` for legacy support

Answer (score 2):

In highcharts, you can use highstock.js and enable `scrollbar`, inclding defition of min/max values.

See simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/fj6d2/

Comment: That would be much easier. However, I noticed that the y-axis values increase and decrease based on where you scroll (which is not an intended behavior). Do you know if I can disable it?

Comment: How can I reprodcue this ? which steps should I do

Comment: I mean in the jsfiddle example that you provided above. If you scroll to the right you can see the y-axis labels change (the max changes from 200 to 250). Can you disable this?

Comment: You need use tickPositioner / tickPositions.